# Deploy an Application on Cloud Foundry Server

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource, cloud-foundry

One problem was occurred when I did deploy the applications
to Cloud Foundry with STS(SpringSource Tool Suite). My deployment procedure as flowing:

1:After the Cloud Foundry was completely installed, Clicked YES to restart STS.
 Select **Window > Show View > Servers**

2:Right-click in the Servers panel and choose **New > Server**
Expand the VMware folder, select Cloud Foudry,and Click **Next**.

3:In this step, I choose VMware Cloud Foundry, and type in user account and password which
 I was signed in the Cloud Foundry website.

4:Click finsh to establish the Cloud Foundry servers.

5:To deploy an application, drag it to the target Cloud Foundry Server. Right click the target Cloud Foundry Server, choose Add and Remove，a problem was occurred at this moment. Therewas no available application to deploy on the Cloud Foundry Server,I had built some Java projects.

I tried server methods to solve the problem,unfortunately ,I was failed, if any help from you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only deploy certain kinds of java projects to cloud foundry.  Inside STS, only Grails, Spring, Roo, and web projects are recognized.

If you want to try something, then create a spring template project: File -> New -> Spring Template Project, then choose a template.  Spring MVC is probably a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry STS plugin is one way to push your apps to cloudfoundry.com
You can also use the CLI tool called vmc.

For installation and how to use the tool, please visit:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html